# SQL Server : query to validate address data from Google API

Tags: sql-server, validation, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering if anyone has any insight into validating address data from a SQL Server database using Google Map's API.

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
Declare @MyTable as Table   
(
    row_index int identity (1,1),
    name varchar(100) null,
    address varchar(100) null,
    city varchar(100) null,
    state varchar(2) null,
    zip int null,
    isvalid bit not null
)

Insert @MyTable Values ('Microsoft', '15010 NE 36th Street', 'Redmond', 'WA', 98052, 0)
Insert @MyTable Values ('Fake Address','123 Blahblah Ln', 'Fresno', 'CA', 93650, 0)
Insert @MyTable Values ('Google', '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway', 'Mountain View', 'CA', 94043, 0)

Select * from @Mytable
```

Is there any way that I can directly query Google from SQL Server to determine whether the address, city, state, and zip are valid addresses and then set the `isvalid` bit to 1?

I see how to do this with JavaScript, but I'm hoping for a purely T-SQL driven solution as I need to schedule a job to identify the bad ones and remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really directly from SQL, no.

You could write a SSIS package that contains C# scripting that utilises the API - this has been experimented with here (albeit in a different way to what you're needing, but you can get the idea):

http://www.sqlmusings.com/2011/03/25/geocode-locations-using-google-maps-v3-api-and-ssis/

If you pulled this off you'd be able to schedule a task using SQL Server Agent that carried out the validation you require.

Comment: Thank you sir.  I'll give that a try.